# Selenium WebDrive - Chrome unexpected alert open

Tags: c#, selenium

Every now and then I get an alert window that has 0 impact on what i'm testing however it throws the exception and the application stops crawling.

How do you make chrome stop with the pop up messages all together?

```
using (var driver = new  ChromeDriver(@"C:\hrtr"))

          unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.125)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: Do you not know when the application under test is going to throw an alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the driver ignore any unexpected alerts by using a specific options.

You can try the below code which is for IE. You can adopt it for Chrome.

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior = OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Ignore;

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Comment: ChromeDriver does not have an equivalent option, which is really unfortunate because I'm getting intermittent alerts and ChromeDriver exits too fast to figure out what the alert is.

The InternetExplorerDriverOptions class: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/IE/InternetExplorerOptions.cs

ChromeDriverOptions class:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeOptions.cs

Comment: There is something for Chrome

Comment: You sure about that? I provided a link to the source code and I didn't see anything in it that provides this functionality. If it is there (and named something completely different), could you take a look and let us know exactly what property provides the same feature?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. But I could not get that at this moment for you.